# Inputting list of lists into dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list

how can I put the following into an already existing dataframe?

```
This is how normal_train[5] looks like:
[[  0 255 107]
 [  0 255 106]
 [  0 255 103]
 ...
 [  0 255  54]
 [  0 255  52]
 [  0 255  51]]

This is how normal_train[4] looks like:
[[  0 255 103]
 [  0 255 104]
 [  0 255 103]
 ...
 [  0 255  55]
 [  0 255  54]
 [  0 255  53]]

data_train['feat'] = normal_train
```

So I have 13 of these entries but the length of values apparently doesn't match.

Length of values (1125) does not match length of index (13)

What do I have to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1, 2, 3]})
df["feat"] = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

but the following doesn't:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1, 2, 3]})
df["feat"] = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

...and raises `ValueError: Length of values (2) does not match length of index (3)`.

It seems like `len(normal_train) == 1125`, but `len(data_train) == 13`. Those should be of the same length.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign it by wrapping it in a Series vector if you're trying to add to an existing df:

```
data_train['feat'] = pd.Series(normal_train)
```